# SQL self join to eradicate duplicate keys

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with below columns:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Hello | NULL |
| A | NULL | WORLD |

I want the above table to transform like below:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Hello | WORLD |

I'm using Snowflake DataWarehouse. Need help in the above transformation using SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select column1,
       max(column2) as column2,
       max(column3) as column3
  from your_table
 group by column1;
```

Comment: perfect. Worked